# Xcode console is black

Tags: xcode, debugging

Some time happens that Xcode console become empty and not responsive to read command.
It disappear the debugger command line console  and I don't find a way to re-show it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't input lldb commands in a active (not paused) program. You should first pause the app (by a break point or etc.) and then you can write commands there.

Also if you need some input from the console, you need commands like `readline()` or etc.